# C# как заполнить таблицу датой и временем

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

такая ситуация, нужно заполнить таблицу датой и временем, каждый час. вот мой код

```
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(dabar);            
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(dt_time_iki.Text);           

        for (DateTime ii11 = dt1; ii11 <= dt2; ii11 = ii11.AddMinutes(60))
        {                
            var index = dg_svorio_kontrole.Rows.Add();
            dg_svorio_kontrole.Rows[index].Cells["svorio_kontrole_data"].Value = ii11.ToString();

        }
```

Всё работает, но если время установлено следующего дня, то цикл не запускается. Например, если теперь: 14:20, а второе время 00:20, то цикл не запускается, так как значение меньше. Есть идеи как можно реализовать ?

Comment: `AddDays(1)`?..

Comment: тогда будет днями считать. а мне нужно каждый час, и если время достигло 24:00 в следующей строке добавляется один день

Answer (score 0):

Вот что мне помогло:

```
if (dt1 > dt2) dt2 = dt2.AddHours(24);
```

Comment: Я то же самое вам предложил, `AddDays(1)` и `AddHours(24)` - это одно и то же. :) Но я рад, что вы разобрались.